# Is it possible to change the file path of the video using javascript?

Tags: javascript, object-tag

I have an object tag in a HTML file:

```
<object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95">
     <param name="FileName" value="../ABC/WildLife.wmv" id="mediaPlayerFile">
     <param name="AutoStart" value="false" />
</object>
```

I want to change the filename using javascript.

What I have so far is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disp_current_directory() {
        var val = document.getElementById('mediaPlayerFile');
        val.attributes['value'].value = "D:\XYZ\WildLife.wmv";
    }

</script>
```

But this doesn't work. :(

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this after the object has been initialized as the parameters supplied using `<param..>` are only used during object creation.

To update this you will have to replace the entire `object` tag with new parameters.

If you want to access the api of the object, take a look at this question [Is there a documented JavaScript API for Windows Media Player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299582/is-there-a-documented-javascript-api-for-windows-media-player)

Comment: Do update this you will have to replace the entire object tag with new parameters....how to do this?