# javascript - changing embedded objects src problem for Firefox (no problem for IE9 or Opera)

Tags: javascript, video

this will be my first question. Sorry for mistakes.

Following  code works in IE9 and Opera but does not work in Firefox.

In Firefox, I am clicking another link and going back to the page that contains the video
then video is starting. Otherwise, video is not starting. (again not starting when refreshing the page)

```
function output_video_URL(id, local_path_of_video, remote_path_of_video) {
    var http_check = getHTTPObject();

    var local_URL = local_server + local_path_of_video;
    var remote_URL = remote_server + remote_path_of_video;

    http_check.open("HEAD", local_path_of_video);
    http_check.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse_check;
    http_check.send(null);


    function handleHttpResponse_check() {
        if (http_check.readyState == 4){
            if (http_check.status == 200) {
                var video = document.getElementById(id);
                video.src = local_URL;
                video.parentNode.Filename = local_URL;
            }
            else if (http_check.status == 404) {
                var video = document.getElementById(id);
                video.src = remote_URL;
                video.parentNode.Filename = remote_URL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<object width="364" height="266" classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" id="mediaplayer1">
  <param name="Filename" value="filmler/canakkeleklipkucuk.wmv" />
  <param name="AutoStart" value="True" />
  <param name="ShowControls" value="false" />
  <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false" />
  <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false" />
  <param name="AutoRewind" value="false" />
  <embed id = "canakkeleklip" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/" width="320" height="240" src="filmler/canakkeleklipkucuk.wmv" autostart="True"  showcontrols="false" showstatusbar="false"  showdisplay="false" autorewind="false"> </embed>
</object>
<script type = "text/javascript"> output_video_URL('canakkeleklip', 'videos/canakkeleklipkucuk.wmv', 'filmler/canakkeleklipkucuk.wmv') </script>
```

Comment: _In Firefox, I am clicking another link_ Where code of this link? It's a html anchor or ?

Comment: What is difference between `local_server` and `remote_server`. They both `http:` ? Where from loaded page with above content: from remote or from local server?

Comment: @Andrew D. they are two different url. I am checking if the video exists on local_URL. If video doesn't exist on local then I am checking the remote_URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you try to set the Filename property. It's not an attribute of the `object` element, it's an element inside it. (The reason that it works in IE and Opera is that they use the `embed` element, not the `object` element.)

Assuming that the `Filename` parameter is the first one, you can use this to set it:

```
video.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('param')[0].value = local_URL;
```

If you don't know the order of the parameter elements, you would have to loop the child nodes and check for the one with the right `name` attribute.

#### Edit:

However, even when actually changing the the parameter value it won't work, as the object is already created. See [Is it possible to change the file path of the video using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857381/is-it-possible-to-change-the-file-path-of-the-video-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for reply
but it does not change anything. video is not playing unless going forward and back.

Comment: @rasitburak: The difference is that you access the correct value, but there is another problem with that as you can't change the value once the object is created. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857381/is-it-possible-to-change-the-file-path-of-the-video-using-javascript You will have to create a new `object` element with the new settings.