# How we can play audio in html page

Tags: php

In my page i have a button called Play

In included windows media player using this tag

```
<embed id="wmpid" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="false" EnableContextMenu="false"  autostart="0" width="200" height="45" loop="false" src="/1.wma"  />
```

The audio is starting when i click on the play contoller.

But when i click on the play button, that i created ,how i can play the audio

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript to play the sound by clicking on a button.

```
  <script>
  function EvalSound(soundobj) {
    var thissound= eval("document."+soundobj);
    thissound.Play();
  }
  </script>

  <embed src="success.wav" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1"
  enablejavascript="true">
```

Here are examples of a link, an image and a button calling the function.

```
  <a href="#" onMouseClick="EvalSound('sound1')">Click here</A>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
It is working in IE.But in mozilla it is not working .Can u give me any solution
In mozilla it showing an error thissound.Play is not a function

Comment: try this link:
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread147248.html
That should solve the problem.

Comment: By the way, if my answer is the solution you were looking for, it would be great if you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle events via JavaScript. Refer [is-there-a-documented-javascript-api-for-windows-media-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299582/is-there-a-documented-javascript-api-for-windows-media-player)

Personally I recommend [Yahoo Media Player](http://developer.yahoo.com/mediaplayer/). Windows Media Player might not work on all platforms. Prefer a [flash based player](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/10-easy-to-implement-flash-based-mp3-players-for-your-website/). You might need to convert wma to mp3.

Comment: "might not work" == *will not* work. Oddly, the Windows Media player never seems to load in my Chrome-on-Linux browser.