# how to ensure the Window media player is in Play mode?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, windows-media-player

Hi in my test case i have to click a "link", after that the application will download a ".wav sound file"..After downloading it plays automatically in the Windows media player..I ensured the WMP is in opened state, but my problem is i have to check weather the windows media player is in play mode or not??

I'm writing script in java..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the WMP with some argument, for example `/Task NowPlaying` might be what you're looking for - [WMP Command Line Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can try [clicking blindly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) on a button/tab (which may or may not be there).

However, there is a WMP API you could use via [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access). See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6042/Interoperating-with-Windows-Media-Player-using-P-I) or [this](https://www.google.cz/search?q=wmp%20api) if the former is too outdated.

Or see [Is there a documented JavaScript API for Windows Media Player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299582/is-there-a-documented-javascript-api-for-windows-media-player)

Comment: thanks for your response man..It really helpful for me..thanks a lot.

Comment: out of curiosity, which part of the answer was the most helpful? What did you do in the end?

Comment: java.lang.Robot class...i didn't get the solution not yet.but i thanked you because, Before your answered i didn't know about the "Robot class", but now i know something about that and to handle system events.